# How to hide a file that even if "Show hidden files and folder is checked" it will be hidden?

Tags: java, c#, file, hide, show-hide

I am trying to hide some files in my pc. If I hide them normally the show hidden files and folder option will still show the file in transparent form.

I have used "attrib +a +s +r +h file" command but it still shows up.

How can I really hide the files properly. Like some hide your files programs can do.

Programming Language: Java or C#;

EDIT: There is a free program that can do this on folders. How do they do it?

http://www.cleanersoft.com/hidefolder/free_hide_folder.htm

If it's a OS problem then there might be a way to this using win32 api. It's probably possible in c# but I don't know how.

Comment: If you hide it, means you can show it later. Do you mean "DELETE" ?

Comment: I thing he needs some kind of wrapper around file or folder using program so that file or folder can be visible through that program only not view option if window explorer view.

Comment: perhaps a wrokaround might be to zip the files you wish to hide in an encrypted zip file so the user cannot open and examine the files?

Comment: No I don't mean to delete it. If I hide it of course I can show it later. But not some unwanted person going through my PC. Hiding file normally doesn't work. Because if "Show hidden files and folders" is checked. It will show the transparent form of the file anyways.

Comment: just encrypt those files so other people cant access it.

Comment: did you try attrib filename +s +h you have used a wrong format see my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to hide some files and programming a program do it are different story.
A hide files software do it job by write some file system filter module (kernel or user space), or via api hooking(it OS spefify). If you just want to hide some files, use a software like http://www.wisecleaner.com/wisefolderhider.html on Windows. If you want to make it your own, you'll need more research on it.

Comment: Your answer is the closest so far.

Comment: You may want to checkout this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32744/Driver-to-Hide-Processes-and-Files

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do..

**Way 1**

- Rename the file with blank character (Alt+0160)
- Create new icon bitmap 32x32 blank (fully white)
- Assign this icon to the file you wanna hide

This way file will be really hidden and not affected by "show hidden files and folder option".

**Way 2**

- Create a folder and place ur files in that folder.
- You can fire up cmd command with C# or Java program.
- Command to lock: ren FolderName Users.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}
- Command to unlock: ren Users.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} FolderName

This will basically rename the folder to control panel. When you open the folder, control panel gets launched and because it is a control panel you cannot delete it.

**Way 3**

- Fire this CMD command from your program: **copy /b Cat.jpg + Secret.zip Cat.jpg**
- This will hide your "Secret.zip" file inside an Cat.jpg.
- To reveal files you need to open Cat.jpg file with WinZip.

Comment: Hmmm these things look cool. By the way... Way 1: If i drag my mouse over a seemingly empty area will it not be selected?

Comment: @UchihaMadara: It will get selected. Also, you can combine Way 1 and 2 to make sure even if the file gets revealed your data will be safe..

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can hide files and folders using "Folder Options" -> "Views" -> "Hidden files and folders" and select the radio button "Dont show hidden files".

```
attrib filename +s +h
```

worked for me on windows 7.

Comment: your the best dude XD :) :P

Comment: I like your sense of Humor but NO.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to hide text documents, you can hide them in plain sight using encryption.

Comment: Actually, you can do that with non-text documents as well.

Comment: Interesting- I'll have to look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I was looking for. But doing this to non text document seems interesting. I will see if it's possible to read JPEG images after encrypting it then decrypting it.

Comment: Should be possible to get the data pixel by pixel, then encrypt that data all using java..  I'll have to try it out once I learn awt better.  Good luck

Comment: You can encrypt _any_ sequence of bytes.